# similar_text not giving expected result

Tags: php

I just wondering, whats happens here. If I am using this:

```
var_dump(similar_text('abcd', 'abcdefg', $percent)); //output: int 4
```

Thats ok, `abcd` in the proper place, so 4 is good result.

Let's change `a` and `b` at the begining of the first variabl:

```
var_dump(similar_text('bacd', 'abcdefg', $percent)); //output: int 3
```

I excpected to `2` or `4` but not `3`. Can somebody explain it to me why is it?

Comment: Its similarity in percentage, not number of characters it matched

Comment: no, percentage will be in `$percent` variable, what I did not use here.

Comment: There's some discussion about it on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136349/how-does-similar-text-work. Long story short, it's probably not doing what you think it is.

Comment: Not familiar with the algorithm used, but I'd suggest that `cd` in the correct location already, probably scoring a full point; and `ab` both contained only one character position differently probably scoring a half-point

Comment: Watchout this: [how-to-improve-php-string-match-with-similar-text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690854/how-to-improve-php-string-match-with-similar-text)

Comment: Can you explain why your expected output  `2 or 4`??

Comment: @FrayneKonok If function does not cares the order, then `a` and `b` could be found in the second string, so it should be `4`. If the function cares the order, then `a` and eithere `b` is not in the same place, in this case shoould  be `2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) uses an algorithm that takes the first letter in the first string that the second string contains, counts that, and throws away the chars before that from the second string.
This is the reason why we get different results.

Iteration for first example

```
  'abcd' vs 'abcdefg' - (1) // 'a' match with 'a' 
  'bcd'  vs 'bcdefg'  - (1) // 'b' match with 'b' 
  'cd'   vs 'cdefg'   - (1) // 'c' match with 'c'
  'd'    vs 'defg'    - (1) // 'd' match with 'd'
  ''     vs 'efg'     - (0) // no match
  Result = 4
```

Iteration for second example

```
  'bacd' vs 'abcdefg'  - (0) // b not match a
  'bacd' vs 'bcdefg'   - (1) // b match b
  'acd'  vs 'cdefg'    - (0) // a not match c
  'cd'   vs 'cdefg'    - (1) // c match c
  'd'    vs 'defg'     - (1) // d match d
  ''     vs 'efg'      - (0) // not match with any elemennt
  Result = 3
```

Comment: I am going to make this post, I also think this.

Comment: I think this is the reason,what you think?

Comment: can you explain me please, why `'cd'   vs 'cdefg'    - (0)` while in the first iteration it is 1, and why `''     vs 'efg' ` is 1 in the second, and 0 in the first? And why `'bacd' vs 'abcdefg'  - (1)` in the second?

Comment: @lolka_bolka could you check the edited answer,If it si confusing please let me know

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation with example. Now it is understable, so I accepted and upvoted it.

Comment: Then I should need to write my own method for this.